# how to find a multilevel dict's elements directly in python

Tags: python, dictionary

```
class Trie:
    root = {}
    END = '/'
    def add(self, wordtuple):
        node = self.root
        for c in wordtuple[0]:
            node = node.setdefault(c,{})
        node[self.END] = (wordtuple[1])

    def find_equal(self, word):
        node = self.root
        for c in word:
            if c not in node:
                return None           
            node = node[c]

        return node['/']
```

I have a trie tree, and construct a nested dictionary, like `root = {'a':{'b':{'m':{'/':(4),'f':{'/':(5)}}}}}`, and I have a prefix string `abm` ,but I want to get all strings begining with `abm` like string `abmf`, what should I do?

Comment: I don't want to search the value like you did, I want to get the the value 6 of key 'f' while geting the value 1 of key 'm'

Comment: Your code doesn't run actually (raises syntax error)

Comment: I have modified it

Comment: @littlely can you explain a little better what you want? It is not clear at all

Comment: I will reopen this since the problem has changed a lot since original post

Comment: Looks like [Efficient partial search of a trie in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46961262/efficient-partial-search-of-a-trie-in-python)